# VueJS + vue-i18n routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Can't figure out how to set up routing and why the current configuration doesn't work.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

URL structure:

```
http://example.com/en
http://example.com/en/about-us
http://example.com/en/sample-page

http://example.com/fr
http://example.com/fr/about-us
http://example.com/fr/sample-page
```

To handle proper redirection I setup beforeEach:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const lang = to.params.lang;

  if ( !['en','fr'].includes(lang) ) {
    return next('en');
  }

  if ( i18n.locale !== lang ) {
    i18n.locale = lang;
  }

  return next();
});
```

And here is the part which I do not understand, why it's not working, **why Home component not loading at all**.

router.js

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:lang',
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home,
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```

Language (locale) switching working fine.

Comment: have you imported the components at the top of the router file?

Comment: In `router.js`, you didn't assign a component of `path: '/:lang'`, so it didn't render anything. Maybe, you should put `component: Home` under `path: '/:lang'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a component to render route `/:lang`. You can create a file and add `<router-view/>` inside or create some anonymous component like:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/:lang',
      component: {
        render: h => h('router-view')
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'home',
          component: Home,
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
})
```